# String with N digits

Tags: java, regex

I need some help with regex in Java.

We have string, and I want that String.matches give me "true" if our string contains `N` digits.

For example(`N = 12`):

```
+012345678900 - true

0123-4567-0000 - true;
```

but:

```
+0123456789 - false

0123-4567-000000 - false.
```

I tried this one `(.*[0-9].*){N}`and this one `^(.*[0-9].*){N}$`. But it was incorrectly.

Comment: Note: not all countries have 10 digits, and not all phone numbers have same number of digits in each country.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try this,

```
^(?:\\D*\\d){12}\\D*$
```

`matches` method won't need anchors, so

```
(?:\\D*\\d){12}\\D*
```

would be enough..

`\\D` matches any character but not of digit. So `(?:\\D*\\d){12}` ensures that there must be any no of non-dgit chars but it must contain exactly 12 digits. Last `\\D*` matches zero or more non-digit characters.